# SQL Server log_reuse_wait_desc is ACTIVE_TRANSACTION but there are no active transactions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transaction-log, dbcc

Just had an issue with a SQL Server 2016 database where this query returned ACTIVE_TRANSACTION for  log_reuse_wait_desc:

```
select name,log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.databases where name='database name'
```

1. Recover mode for the database was simple.
2. sys.dm_tran_database_transactions reported no active transactions (for any database).
3. Active log usage for the database (from sys.dm_db_log_stats) was around 800MB.
4. No backup was run during the period in question.

This state persisted for 18 hours until this was run:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'database log file' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
```

That cleared the ACTIVE_TRANSACTION state and the active log usage dropped to a fraction of a MB.

Is there some minimum amount of log that needs to be used before the log gets cleared? I'm not seeing this issue on a number of other servers with the same configuration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log can't be reused until a database checkpoint writes all the dirty pages to the data files, and automatic checkpoints don't happen on a fixed schedule:

> The time interval between automatic checkpoints can be highly
> variable. A database with a substantial transaction workload will have
> more frequent checkpoints than a database used primarily for read-only
> operations. Under the simple recovery model, an automatic checkpoint
> is also queued if the log becomes 70 percent full.

[Database Checkpoints - Automatic Checkpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/database-checkpoints-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#AutomaticChkpt)

Hannah Vernon explains this behavior in more detail here:

> a single checkpoint will be issued when the log becomes 70 % full.
> Once this checkpoint has been issued, further checkpoints may not be
> issued even thought the log is over 70% full, even if the automatic
> checkpoint resulted in no log truncation activity. However, if further
> transactions are generated, and the database engine believes the
> recovery time will be longer than the configured recovery interval,
> SQL Server will issue automatic checkpoints frequently as long as
> transactions are being generated. If no transactions are being
> generated, no automatic checkpoints will be issued.

[CHECKPOINT and Simple Recovery Model](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/troubleshooting/checkpoint-and-simple-recovery-model/)

So your

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'database log file' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
```

either directly or indirectly caused a checkpoint.